When replying to sync, git fetch, or git clone, bad packet length xxxxx is reported
When I execute repo sync to pull a large project, I will report a Bad packet length xxxxx error, and sometimes I will also report this error when using git clone. How should I handle this?
Error info:
yangbinbin@pvt-BianYiJi012:~/8678_single$ repo init -u ssh://yangbinbin@192.168.1.234:29415/MT8678/platform/manifest -b master -g default,notdefault  -m pvt-single-alps-release-u0.mp1-liber.auto-spm-default.xml --no-repo-verify --repo-url=https://gerrit-googlesource.proxy.ustclug.org/git-repo

yangbinbin@pvt-BianYiJi012:~/8678_single$ repo sync -c -f -j4 --no-repo-verify --optimized-fetch
warning: -f/--force-broken is now the default behavior, and the options are deprecated
Fetching: 68% (1268/1862) 25:05 | 4 jobs | 8:08 platform/prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86 @ prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86Bad packet length 2647955583.
Finished discarding for 192.168.1.234 port 29415
Finished discarding for 192.168.1.234 port 29415
Finished discarding for 192.168.1.234 port 29415
Finished discarding for 192.168.1.234 port 29415
Finished discarding for 192.168.1.234 port 29415
Finished discarding for 192.168.1.234 port 29415
Finished discarding for 192.168.1.234 port 29415



System info："Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS"
CPU: 32
Threads: 2
Memory:125G

Repo version：
yangbinbin@pvt-BianYiJi012:~$ repo version
<repo not installed>
repo launcher version 2.45
       (from /usr/bin/repo)
git 2.25.1
Python 3.8.10 (default, Nov 22 2023, 10:22:35)
[GCC 9.4.0]
OS Linux 5.15.0-60-generic (#66~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 25 09:41:30 UTC 2023)
CPU x86_64 (x86_64)
Bug reports: https://issues.gerritcodereview.com/issues/new?component=1370071

I tried to add ControlMaster auto and ControlPersist yes in ~/. ssh/config, but the output only did not display the information for Bad packet length xxxx and Finished discarding for 192.168.1.234 port 29415, which still got stuck.

Please don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.

2647955583 bits is a big packet. How long did the process run before it returned that?

About 20 minutes
